# Stop Firefox's Pop-ups from stealing focus

Tags: firefox, popupwindow

My job is working on a website using Forefox, that website will promt a pop-up every 1 minute to give me a code. When the pop-up window appears, it'll display on top of all other windows and steals the focus. It's so annoying.
When i'm writing Word/Excel it causes mistyping, and that pop-up will minimize some full-screen application like Video Player/Games.
I've tried:
-Set working windows always on top - when i work with 5-10 programs a time it will be more annoyed.
-Change **dom.disable_window_flip** and **browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground** - NOT working.
I'm not sure if this problem come from Firefox or Windows's default setting for a new window pop-up.
Could anyone give me a solution for this case?

Thanks in advance